# NGINX redirection not working for localhost but works fine for 127.0.0.1

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am using nginx within a docker container. The redirection of 127.0.0.1 works fine, but the localhost does not redirect to my api.

I can access my api with http:127.0.0.1, and localhost:443 but not localhost on its own.

Thanks for your help

```
server {
  # listen 80;

  # this server listens on port 80
  listen 80 default_server;

  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name http://localhost 127.0.0.1;

  location / {
    # a bunch of boilerplate proxy configuration


    # the real magic is here where we forward requests to the address that the Node.js server is running on
    proxy_pass http://api:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

}


server {
  listen 443;

  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://api:3000;
  }

}
```